# How do I get results from LINQ to SQL query to partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to get the following results from the Controler action method to the partial view. Typically I just use a model and reference at the top of the page. But I think 'results' is different because it is coming from the LINQ to SQL and don't know how to reference in the view so I can use it to iterate over the results to display.

```
     [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult SelectUnits()
    {

        var results = (from stats in db.t_harvest      
                       orderby stats.unit_number                     
                       select new
                       {
                           stats.unit_number,   

                       }).Distinct().ToList();


        return PartialView(results);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a strongly typed partial since the return list is of Anonymous Types (IE: `new { ... }`).

However, since you're returning only 1 value there's no need for it.

```
var results = (from stats in db.t_harvest      
               orderby stats.unit_number                     
               select stats.unit_number).Distinct().ToList();

return PartialView(results);
```

So if unit_number is an int then make your partial views model an `IEnumerable<int>`.

In the case that you do need to send an anonymous type back, make your partial views model of type `dynamic`.

Just as a word of warning, be careful with `dynamic` (and `ViewBag`, which is also `dynamic`) since syntax errors (such as a type-o when accessing a property on it) will be caught at *runtime* instead of *compile* time. For this reason I personally prefer strongly typed views where applicable.

---

There are 3 ways you can pass data to your view:

```
ViewData["SomeName"] = 12345;
ViewBag.SomeName = 12345; // MVC3+
ViewData.Model = 12345; // Same as doing: return PartialView(12345);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return a list of anonymous objects, so one option is to access them using the dynamic object (`ViewBag`) that is already within each view (if you are using MVC3 that is)

[Here is a good article on ViewBag and ViewData](http://brendan.enrick.com/post/Difference-Between-ViewBag-and-ViewData-in-MVC-3.aspx), where ViewData is just another way that you could pass this to the view.

This is rough and untested, but I believe this should work:

Controller.cs

```
ViewBag.Results = results;
return PartialView();
```

PartialView

```
@(foreach(var result in ViewBag.Results)
    {
     result.unit_number.ToString();//This line should print out the HTML
    }
)
```

Comment: This code will work but the explanation behind it is incorrect. You *can* pass an anonymous type back to your view through the model. There is no difference, you can use ViewData[""], ViewBag or the Model. What matters is what type you have specified as your model on the view page itself.

Comment: Yes, I have given one example of how to pass it back. I will make that a little more explicit.